# Making a shiny application using YOLOv5

Tags: python, r, shiny, yolo

I want to create a dashboard application in Shiny in Rstudio using Python.
The objective is to deploy a TensorFlow model inside a Shiny app. We will build a model that can classify insects in images; then, we will build a Shiny app that lets you upload an image and get predictions from this model.
My idea is to create a dashboard that uses a training neural network (Yolov5) (`model = 'best.pt'`) to identify the targets with a bounding box in a JPG image chosen. I try to draft this:

```
# app.py
from shiny import UI
from yolo_v5_inference import Inference
from PIL import Image as view
from IPython.display import Image
```

and

```
# ui.page

# Load the model
model = r'best.pt' # Better model trains using Yolov5 neural network in Python

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello TensorFlow!"),
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: File upload
      fileInput("image_path", label = "Input a JPEG image")
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Output: 
      textOutput(outputId = "prediction"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "image")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  image <- reactive({
    req(input$image_path)
    jpeg::readJPEG(input$image_path$datapath)
  })
  
  output$prediction <- renderText({
    
    img <- image() %>% 
      array_reshape(., dim = c(1, dim(.), 1))
    standart = Inference(crops_path=imgage, yolov5_model_path=model, conf_threshold=0.5, rescale=(1.5, 1.5), save_rescaled=True)
    standart.standart
    
    paste0("The predicted bounding-box ")
  })
  
  output$image <- renderPlot({
    plot(as.raster(image()))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please, could someone help me?

Comment: It looks like you're basing this on some sort of template. Can you link to it? I've used the R Shiny package and the Python Shiny package but I've never used both together and have no idea how you would. It's also confusing to me you have a UI and server in your R app. So what is app.py doing?

Comment: I changed a little bit my question. I tried to create something inspired by the post: https://www.jayasekara.blog/2021/07/creating-interactive-dashboards-in-r-shiny-with-python-scripts.html

Comment: That script passes R data to Python with `reticulate`. You'll need to do something like that - you can't just put Python code in your .R file as you have done here (e.g. `standart = Inference(crops_path=imgage, yolov5_model_path=model, conf_threshold=0.5, rescale=(1.5, 1.5), save_rescaled=True)`) and expect it to work...